# How to validate access token in Ionic 3?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, ionic3, access-token, laravel-passport

I'm working on Ionic-Laravel app, and using Laravel Passport for authentication. These are my questions about authentication:

**Q1:** Is there any way I can validate the access token in ionic app (like in JWT `.isTokenExpired()`)?

**Q2:** When User-X logs in, the access token is either stored in SQLite or LocalStorage. If User-Y steals this access tokens, can he log in as User-X? Or my understanding about access token is wrong?

**Q3:** If I'm right about **Q2**, what is the better approach to store the access token in the ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

I Have worked with laravel and ionic/cordova before.
The proper approach would be to send the stored access token on client side & user email , passowrd with each requests and first check if it is not expired and after that check if that token is assigned to the user who is requesting by fetching that user's model using the email and password received in the request with the token , if it is then execute the function else , return error. Therefore you will not have to worry about token if it gets stolen since all your functions will ask for token with that user's email and password.